# JMeter - Save responsse to a file: Change Directory?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to change which directory the "Save responses to a file" listener saves the files?  Currently it saves to bin directory.  I would like to save them to a different one.

Comment: It's set as part of the file prefix. The caveat seems to be that the directories must already exist (JMeter can't create them).

Answer (score 3):

Add the full path / directory where you want to save the response in `Filename prefix` input field in the `Save responses to a file` listener e.g. `C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\New folder\test01`